# Class-template with zero-size array due to non-type template parameter: how to prevent warning?

Tags: c++, templates

I use code like the following minimal example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

constexpr uint8_t size = 0; // sort of global config option

template<typename T = char, uint8_t L = size>
struct A {
    T f() {
        if constexpr(L > 0) {
            return data[0];
        }  
        return T{0};
    }
    int x = 0;
    T data[L];
};

int main() {
    A x; 
    x.f();
}
```

Now I changed the compiler (g++) settings to -pedantic and I get the following warning:

`ISO C++ forbids zero-size array [-Wpedantic]`

This is absolutely ok, but I wonder how can I prevent this message?

Comment: You want to disable warnings, or doesn't have member when `size == 0` ?

Comment: I think the best way would be to omit the member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could specialize your `A` struct for the case where `L == 0`:

```
template <typename T>
struct A<T, 0>
{
  T f() { return {0}; }
};
```